# how to refer to group found with regex in visual studio code search & replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, in replace, I want to refer to what found in search with regex.

I thought this was done with `$1`, `$2`, etc. but I could not.

[image]

then:

[image]

What I want to achive is to get:

[image]

How can I refer in replace to what is found in search?

**Note:**
What I really aim is not the one in this example. It is only an example to explain what I need: refer to what is found. So, please don't mind offer other ways to replace "spaces with ->"spaces<-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, nothing is "found" because you don’t make use of any capture groups in your pattern.

If you need to refer to the whole match, use `$0` in the `Replace` field.

If you *really* want to use `$1` instead for whatever reason, wrap your pattern in `Find` with parenthesis `()` to indicate it should be treated explicitly as a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the same syntax but in the search bar (Ctrl+Shift+F).

edit: I was able to refer to the group this way:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdJol.png)

Comment: It gives me the same result.

Comment: I could already infer what I was missing from your example, so +1, but I have to mark as answer the other as it actually answers it. Thanks!